# How it is possible for a simple for loop in java to use all available cores?

Tags: time-complexity

Welcome everybody!

I was running today a simple computational complexity test with LinkedList:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Byte> list = new LinkedList<>();

    for (int j = 0; j < 50_000_000; j++) {
        list.add((byte) j);
    }

    for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        list.get(5_000_000 * j - 1);
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Percent of the problem: " + j * 10 + ", time: "
                + (t2 - t1));
    }

}
```

While I noticed that during population of the list with object all cores of the CPU were used 100% I have 4 + 4 hyper. Is is possible that Java actually used multiple threads to somehow populate the list?

Comment: I can confirm that this is using all four cores on my computer. That's pretty odd...

Comment: It's quite likely that your JVM has some other threads running for it's own purposes - garbage collection, JIT compilation, etc... So your JVM may have been using all cores, but it might not have directly been your code doing it...

Comment: What I suspect is that the CPU is consumed by GC threads moving objects from Eden Space to old generation. I will try to prove this today.

Comment: The JVM doesn't simply throw OutOfMemoryException, it will try to get some memory free first, and this consumes CPU.